# use latest casperjs as portable version via batch

Tags: javascript, batch-file, phantomjs, casperjs

*disclaimer*: *All the answers I found at the thread over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510623/using-casperjs-as-a-portable-installation) are not working for the casperjs and phantomjs-versions are newer (at least I think that's the cause).*

So... I've created a bunch of tests using the latest version of casperjs from its [master-branch](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs) - NOT(!) the one aquired via download-link, for I needed to use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) 2.0 due to some bugs with the 1.9.8 version preventing me to do my tests. I'm on a win7 64bit environment.

It all worked out very well, but now I'm trying to automate the execution of the tests via a batch-file as described in the thread I mentioned in the disclaimer - so that I don't have the PATH-variable.

I tried to use the following script alongside with putting the phantomjs-file together with my casperjs-file in the rootdirectory:

```
@ECHO OFF
set CASPER_PATH=%~dp0
set CASPER_BIN=%CASPER_PATH%\bin\
set ARGV=%*
call phantomjs "%CASPER_BIN%bootstrap.js" --casper-path="%CASPER_PATH%" --cli %ARGV%
```

This is my filestructure so far:

[image]

While starting the batch, I always face the following error: `CasperError: Cannot find package.json at C:\package.json`

And I have no clue how to change this anymore. Hope anyone could help me out here!

Comment: `set CASPER_BIN=%CASPER_PATH%bin\ ` instead of `set CASPER_BIN=%CASPER_PATH%\bin\ `? `%~dp0` contains a trailing backslash! Windows CLI resolves doubled `\\ ` in a path well to a single `\ ` but what about _casper_?

Comment: I just tried to remove the \, but without success. Still get the same message :/ but thanks so far!

Comment: I'd force `echo ON` to see the `call phantomjs ...` line correctness.  Could you cause working `phantomjs ` line using hard-coded path(s) and parameters?