# Execute CasperJS script by GhostDriver

Tags: java, phantomjs, casperjs, ghostdriver

Can be CasperJS script send through GhostDriver to PhantomJS. Let say I have some Java App and through this app I will generate some CasperJS script and then send through the GhostDriver to PhantomJS.

Thank you for response.

Comment: CasperJS' entrypoint is the bootstrap.js which itself loads all the remaining modules. It should be possible. (See [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102134/1816580), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19857139/1816580) and [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19751516/1816580)). Anyway, you would need to use the [`driver.executePhantomJS`](http://javadox.com/com.github.detro.ghostdriver/phantomjsdriver/1.1.0/org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs/PhantomJSDriver.html#executePhantomJS(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method